# Save kendo grid batch edit along with other field

Tags: kendo-ui, batch-processing

I have a scenario where I want to save kendo grid batch edit and other fields in the form in one submit button press. I want to use this scenario since I have to save the whole form in one sql transaction.

Comment: I was thinking that I can get data from grid by using $("#YourGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view() and then send this data to Controller. But don't know how to go forward from this thought, since I am very new to MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You might get it implementing a [`transport.parameterMap`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportparametermap-function) function where you create the data structure that you want to send.

Example:

```
function(options, operation) {
    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
        return {   
            data:   options.models,
            field1: $("#form_field1").val(),
        };
    }
}
```

Where `data` is the original data and `field1` is the one got from your `form` and in an `html` `input` field which `id` is `form_field1`.

Alternatively, you can use [`transport.update.data`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportupdatedata-objectstringfunction) where you can define extra data to send to the server on an `update` (same exists for `read`, `destroy` and `create`).

Here you would have something like:

```
transport: {
    update: {
        data: function() {
            return {
                field1: $("#form_field1").val()
            }
        }
    }
}
```